# Get Username from service host

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, web-config

I created an WCF service that is hosted by IIS. It offers a few methods specified in a Contract (interface).This works great, no problems here.

```
    <services>
        <service name="myNamespace.KliAPI" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="largeDataBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" name="test" contract="myNamespace.ImyAppAPI" />
            <endpoint address="help" kind="webHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="helpPageBehavior" contract="myNamespace.ImyAppAPI" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Im using a customAuthenticator is the web.config to handle the login logic. it validates username and password against a database and returns TRUE or FALSE depending if the credentials matched a database record.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="CustomAuthenticator" type="myNamespace.CustomAuthenticator, myNamespace.IISServiceHost" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**The problem:**
I want to be able to get/read the username that was supplied to the CustomAuthenticator class in the methods that is exposed through the contract interface *ImyAppAPI*. How can I share that information from the Host to the Service method? I think it is especially tricky because the methods that are exposed are not programmatically made, instead that are made automatically by specifying a contract in the web.config file.

Example:

```
public string[] DownloadUserSpecificData(int[] filters){
    //Here I want access to the username
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```